# Reverse json-stringify-safe

Tags: javascript, json, next.js, circular-reference

In my NextJS React app I use `getInitialProps` to fetch data that has circular references in. The `getInitialProps` method serialises using JSON.stringify, so when circular references are involved NextJS throws [this error](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/errors/circular-structure.md).

A solution is to use the [json-stringify-safe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stringify-safe) package which works like this:

```
const stringify = require('json-stringify-safe');

const test = { a: 'hello' };
test.b = test;

const testWithoutCircularReferences = JSON.parse(stringify(test));
console.log(testWithoutCircularReferences);
// Output: {"a":"hello","b":"[Circular ~]"}
```

For the object to be usable in my React, I need to reverse this, but this widely used package doesn't seem to have a `parse` function, or something similar to reverse the original stringify I did. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Not with json-stringify-safe. As its name implies, it supplies only the "stringify" part. I suggest using [a different module](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=circular+json) that's intended for two-way use.

Comment: @JordanRunning Thanks for the input. I did try a couple of different packages such as flatted, but unfortunately that completely changes the object structure, which is no good when using propTypes in React.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/samchon/typia for Typescript based I/O. Single line parse/stringify/validate etc. But you need Typescript classes.